# Patch update of Microsoft .Net Framework 4.6.1(KB4040973) causing issue in the WPF Combobox

Tags: wpf, windows, frameworks, windows-update, .net-4.6.1

Our application was created using WPF with .Net framework 3.5 and that rendering in the Internet Explorer.  In my office, yesterday(20-SEP-2017) patch got updated for the laptop and that shown in the below.

```
 Update for Microsoft Windows (KB4040980)
 Security Update for Microsoft Windows (KB4040966)
 Security Update for Microsoft Windows(KB4038779)
 Security Update for Microsoft Windows (KB4036586)  
 Update for Microsoft Windows (KB4019990)
 Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 (KB4040973)
 Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 (KB4040957)
```

Prior to this update, the data to combobox was showing correctly and after this update combo box value is displayed briefly then disappeared.

In one of our servers still, this patch didn't get updated so that we can see the correct value in the combo box.

Tried:

1. uninstall 4.6.1 frameworks update - didn't work
2. Installed 4.6.1 frameworks from Microsoft site- didn't work
3. Installed 4.6.2 frameworks from Microsoft site- didn't work

Please provide suggestion/fix to overcome this issue.

Comment: If you don't want to take the time to provide a repro so somebody can propose a workaround then just call Microsoft Support.  It is their job to support the product, it is a job.

Comment: Thank you @Hans for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

> Since KB 4041083 / KB 4040973 (Security and Quality Rollup for the .NET Framework 3.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 
>   4.6.1, 4.6.2, and 4.7 for Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1: 
>   September 12, 2017) was installed rendering no longer works and I end up with a blank image. 
>   This only seems to be a problem when running in a service and not when running via a windowed application.

[KB 4041083 / KB 4040973 has broken WPF Rendering in Services](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0f14f14c-5cd3-4505-9168-2ef9dc1f7031/kb-4041083-kb-4040973-has-broken-wpf-rendering-in-services?forum=netfxbcl)

[Rendering issues after the September 12, 2017, .NET Security and Quality Rollups are installed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4043601/rendering-issues-after-the-september-12-2017-net-security-and-quality)

Comment: Thank you, Sean, for your reply.